# Why mouseleave triggers event on child when capturing is true

Tags: javascript

I have a child in my div that i don't want to trigger the mouseleave event and still use event's capturing, so why mouseleve event triggers when capturing is set to true in:

```
.addEventListener('mouseleave',() => { 
  count.textContent = ++count.textContent;
},true)
```

But it's not the case when bubbling is used instead - capturing is set to false?

```js
let count = document.getElementById('count');
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('mouseleave',() => { 
  count.textContent = ++count.textContent;
},true)
```

```css
.parent{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.child{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
Count:<div class="count" id="count">0</div>
<div class='parent' id='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

useCapture

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate
>   capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type
>   will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched
>   to any EventTargets beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed
>   explanation.

So whenever cursor leaves the child, the event is dispatched to parent causing it trigger again as `mouseleave` event handler is defined in parent.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't really answer the question why mouseleave triggers on capturing, but not on bubbling.

Comment: With bubbling the parent is not triggered with stop.propagation(), not the other way around. Also that doesn't really answer why mouseleave work that way?

Comment: Actually capturing true will just trigger the event on the way down and not on the way up bubbling. Stop propagation would work that way if i have 2 events 1 on child and 1 on parent and when I enter the child the parents event is capturing and not bubbling so it is triggered and if I have stopPropagation I will not trigger child's event.

Comment: When you leave target(child), as you have initiated capture, the registered listener will be called first even if you an event already defined on child. Try it out without using anything like stopPropagation()

Comment: there are 2 events mouseleave and mouseout. mouseleave is supposed to work that way when you leave the child the event is not triggered. What capturing does is if you have 2 events one on child and one on parent the parent event is called first. I don't see why capturing or bubbling matters here where the event is only one. Also the stop propagation part was for the other answer sorry.

Comment: You say will be called first? Where there is only one event to be called anyways.

Comment: My point was it doesn't matter whether there is an event defined for child or not parent event will be called when you use capturing

Comment: That is true, but I could have another event on the document that I want to trigger first after the mouseleave event. This was just an example I just wanted to know why it is working that way.

Comment: This is the reason, as you are using capturing parent is capturing the child's event and triggering when cursor is leaving child. I hope I am able to explain it to you

Comment: Read more about capturing events to understand it better

Comment: Capturing is parent's event triggering first and then the child event bubbling is the other way around. But here there is ONLY one event which is the paren'ts event. The parent is not capturing the child's event the event is on the parent.

Comment: I kinda think you are the one who needs to read on that. The event starts from the window than to the body and so on if any of those elemnts have an event that is capture on it triggers first otherwise it goes to the element on the point of the mouse and goes back again in bubbling mode and triggering every event on the dom up that is capture off

Comment: But here capturing doesn't matter because the event is on the parent so leaving the child will always trigger one event which is the parent's event.

Comment: First of all there is no bubbling when you set event capture. Secondly with capture when you leave child first window event will be called which is not defined then body event will be  called which is also not defined then your parent which is defined so it will be called, then child which is again not defined.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. So the code works correctly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ksnpmav/  - Here we have 3 events when your mouse hovers the blue div first the top parent's event is called - capturing then the event on the top of the mouse then bubbling has started so it is coming back towards the parent elements checking for events and the parent without the capture on is triggered. So there is both bubbling and capturing happening towards and from the element on the top of the mouse

Comment: Why are you using bubbling in your example?

Comment: because you said that there is no bubbling present when capture is on when they are both present first capturing is happening from the window towards the elements triggering all parent elements with capture on then bubbling begins triggering all parent elements without capture on

Answer (score 0):

Just add `pointer-events: none;` to your child div.

Comment: yes, but my child also has an event. I know how to work around it, but my question is why it doesn't let me use capturing.

Comment: @ivaylo Oh, right on. I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example helps you better understand event capturing better.
When you leave the black container mouse leave of gparent and parent will be triggered resulting in +2

But when you leave child still it will be +2 as no event is defined on child

```js
let count = document.getElementById('count');
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('mouseleave',() => { 
  count.textContent = ++count.textContent;
},true)

document.getElementById('gparent').addEventListener('mouseleave',() => { 
  count.textContent = ++count.textContent;
},true)
```

```css
 

.gparent{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.parent{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top: 20%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.child{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
Count:<div class="count" id="count">0</div>
<div class='gparent' id='gparent'>
   <div class='parent' id='parent'>
     <div class='child'></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wrote my example https://jsfiddle.net/5ksnpmav/2/ here see that bubbling and capturing are both present at any time

Comment: yes, but in my example I have only 1 event so your example is irelevant it is obvious that when there are 2 events both events will be called

Comment: This has nothing to do with capturing if you change the event to mouseout and remove capturing you have the same result

Comment: It is the different behaviour of mouseout and mouseleave not capturing, no matter if we have capturing or not both events on the child should trigger, because it is a child of it's parents, if you change mouseleave to mousedown and try the same thing with capturing on or off you will see that capturing has nothing to do with the final result.

Comment: mouseout and mouseleave has mothing to do with event capturing. mouseleave and mouseout are similar but differ in that mouseleave does not bubble and mouseout does.

Comment: And we are not dealing with bubbling here anyway

Comment: The reason you get the same result with mouseout and not using capture is obvious. "mouseout doesn't bubble"

Comment: Tell me the reason why you think the parent event should not fire when cursor leaves child with event capturing?